# how to make date Auto Format in input textbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-4.0

when input yyyyMMdd format in textbox, that will automatically change to yyyy/MM/dd format  for example: if your type 20180428, that will change to 2018/04/28

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Consider reading this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Try to provide examples of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing built-in JavaScript functions such as parseInt to get the input element from a string to an integer, you are able to apply logic with helper functions to get to the date formatting you desire. e.g. if the day value is greater than 31, default return 1 instead to automatically guide the user from inputting a day more than 31

[MDN JavaScript parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Afterwards, with the use of Regex, you can manipulate the user's initial data input (YYYYmmDD) to a format you want to change it to (YYYY/mm/DD).

[Regex](https://regexr.com/)

I found an online tutorial outlining this very process below:

[Auto-format Date Input by Envato Tuts+](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/KMWqRr)

```js
var date = document.getElementById('date');

function checkValue(str, max) {
  if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
    var num = parseInt(str);
    if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
    str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
  };
  return str;
};

date.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  this.type = 'text';
  var input = this.value;
  if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
  var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });
  if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
  if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
  var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
    return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
  });
  this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
});

date.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  this.type = 'text';
  var input = this.value;
  var values = input.split('/').map(function(v, i) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });
  var output = '';
  
  if (values.length == 3) {
    var year = values[2].length !== 4 ? parseInt(values[2]) + 2000 : parseInt(values[2]);
    var month = parseInt(values[0]) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(values[1]);
    var d = new Date(year, month, day);
    if (!isNaN(d)) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = d.toString();
      var dates = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()];
      output = dates.map(function(v) {
        v = v.toString();
        return v.length == 1 ? '0' + v : v;
      }).join(' / ');
    };
  };
  this.value = output;
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}
form input {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 3;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
form input.error {
    border-color: #ff0000;  
}
form label.error {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

label {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em
}
form small {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    align-self: ;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <label for="amount">Date</label>
  <input type="text" id="date" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
</form>
```

Comment: How to get MM/YY?